# i can't rails s with redis-store

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

my rails is 3.2.8

i have gem like below

```
#gemfile
gem 'redis', '3.0.2'
gem 'redis-store', '1.1.3'
gem 'redis-rails'

#session_store.rb
Application.config.session_store :redis_session_store
```

then rails s

it report error like below

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/magicstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:140:in `const_get': uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Session::RedisSessionStore (NameError)
    from /Users/magicstudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:140:in `session_store'
```

why?

Comment: redis and redis-store are not necessary in your gemfile. Maybe this screws things up

Comment: i find problem, Application.config.session_store :redis_store,not redis_session_store.i don't know why?redis-store's document said redis_session_store

Comment: Any ideas how to get redis-store 1.1.3 work with rails 3.0.17 ?

Comment: It's not compatible. I went through this with Rails 3.0.10. In answer to your other question about why :redis_store vs :redis_session_store. :redis_session_store is the store name in the old version of the gem. While I'm not entirely sure why it was renamed, the newer versions  of redis-store and redis-rails expect :redis_store.